# stream_socket_enable_crypto(): SSL operation failed with code in laravel with gmail security already open

Tags: ssl, laravel-5.8

**My work in env file**

my mail driver `MAIL_DRIVER=smtp`
My host `MAIL_HOST=smtp.gmail.com`
my port `MAIL_PORT=587`
My mail `address MAIL_USERNAME=xxxxxx@gmail.com`
my password `MAIL_PASSWORD=yyyyyy`

```
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=tls
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you need to edit your php.ini file. Open it up, and find the text `;extension=php_openssl.dll` and then remove the semi-colon from the beginning. You'll need to save and restart in order for the effects to take place.

Hope this helps.